# entitymanger loses connection after a failed transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions, jboss7.x, seam, entitymanager

i have an application running on seam 2.3, ejb 3 and mysql 5.6. currently trying out a bulk upload kinda functionality (takes values from a csv and saves them to the database)

here if all records are fine, everything gets committed to database, but if there is an incorrect record the transaction fails and entity manager loses connection to database.
any operation like query.getResultSet(), em.persist() fail from this point.

All records from this point error out with the below exception (stacktrace). I am using userTransaction to commit one record at a time ... so that things don't rollback.

```
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) get role err: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)
ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261)
...

16:15:44,275 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
16:15:44,279 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
16:15:44,283 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
16:15:44,288 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
16:15:44,291 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
16:15:44,295 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
16:15:44,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHand
ler.java:82)
16:15:44,302 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.jav
a:138)
16:15:44,306 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
16:15:44,309 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at $Proxy94.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
16:15:44,312 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
16:15:44,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(Statem
entPreparerImpl.java:166)
16:15:44,319 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145
)
...

16:15:44,369 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
16:15:44,375 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:137)
16:15:44,380 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionP
rovider.java:67)
16:15:44,385 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSession
Impl.java:276)
16:15:44,393 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
16:15:44,412 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    ... 94 more
16:15:44,415 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
16:15:44,418 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.
java:362)
16:15:44,422 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.j
ava:464)
16:15:44,427 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
16:15:44,444 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    ... 97 more
16:15:44,447 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAc
tion: 0:ffff0a6a6520:25c36e83:51de8ae5:24 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
16:15:44,464 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.
java:352)
```

**code snippets:**

```
try
{
UserTransaction utx = Transaction.instance();
getRole(newUser, em, utx);
    commit(newUser, em, utx);
    log.info("after flush::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
    }catch (Exception e) {

       System.out.println("Inside Exception !!!!!!!!");
       em.clear();
}

public void getRole(User newUser, EntityManager em, UserTransaction utx)
{
    try
    {     

        Role newRole = new Role();
        System.out.println("is connection open: " + em.isOpen());
        Query roleQuery = em
            .createQuery("from Role role where role.roleId=:roleId");
        roleQuery.setParameter("roleId", 1);

        List<Role> listRole = new ArrayList<>();

        listRole = roleQuery.getResultList();

        newUser.setRole(newRole);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("get role err: " + e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


 public void commit(User newUser, EntityManager em, UserTransaction utx)
  {
  try
     {
        // em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        System.out.println("before utx begin");
        utx.begin();
        System.out.println("before em persist");
        em.persist(newUser);
        System.out.println("before em flush");
        System.out.println("before em begin: " + utx.getStatus() + ": "
            + utx.isActive() + ": " + utx.isNoTransaction());

        em.flush();
        System.out.println("before em commit");
        utx.commit();
    } 
 }
```

Comment: can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Added the code snippets